# In online chess with long time controls, does having a title encourage opponents to cheat against you?

Tags: online-chess, cheating, titles

I was looking through the [top classical players](https://lichess.org/player/top/200/classical) list on LiChess, and I'm gradually improving.  I noticed I'm catching up with [IM Eric Rosen](https://lichess.org/@/EricRosen), which I found surprising (I'm nowhere near that strong).

So I went through his [rated losses](https://lichess.org/@/EricRosen/search?perf=3&mode=1&players.a=ericrosen&players.loser=ericrosen&sort.field=d&sort.order=desc): his opponent cheated ([1](https://lichess.org/1ssFwIlm), [2](https://lichess.org/wf3FXgcE) (probably), [3](https://lichess.org/8f7Ehg7I/), [4](https://lichess.org/5ZIZLyjZ)) in all but [one game](https://lichess.org/3zDCHkgB) (which seems to involve a mouse slip).  They don't just win---they crush him without problems.

I speculate that he encounters more cheating than I do because he has his title on display---his opponents want an IM scalp, and cheat to obtain it.  However, maybe this is not accurate.

**Question**: In online chess with long time controls, does having a title encourage opponents to cheat against you?

I'm hoping a titled player will describe their experiences with and without their titled displayed online.

Comment: Bare in mind that rating lost with cheaters is restored when they are detected, so in the end it doesn't really affect your elo. Yes its annoying but it doesn't take your rating down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've displayed an FM title and never noticed a problem with cheating once. Your question is the first time I've ever thought about the concept of someone wanting to cheat *more* against a titled player.

If anything, most players would want the opportunity to get to play a titled player, and wouldn't waste it by cheating with an engine. How do you know that his opponents were cheating in most of his losses?

Comment: Most of his opponents aren't cheating. But in the games that OP linked to, those accounts were banned from lichess for using engine assistance. So we can confirm that lichess thinks they were cheating.

Comment: I was just confused since she said that his opponents cheated in all but one game (out of his rated losses).

Answer (score 1):

A title sometimes attracts cheating, but those cheating against a titled player (or generally a strong player) are easily identifiable. Usually they are below average players having played a small number of games (to climb to that rating of a titled player) on an account used particularly for cheating.

However, I don't see any point of doing this. The more common intention for an amateur is to test their skills against a titled player, when they get the chance. So, as a titled player, it is more likely to get an opponent wanting to test themselves against you rather than a noob trying to cheat and score an illegal win.